# IQ test puzzles - diagonal line shapes, curly line shapes

Tags: pattern, progressive-matrix

What is correct answer for these two IQ puzzles and why?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 20):

These are effectively the same puzzle.

> Divide each image into 4 lines, preserve one half of them across rows and the other across columns.

Puzzle 4

> [image: Graphical solution of Puzzle 4]
>
>  The top here has some lines flipped diagonally, which is strange.

Puzzle 10

> [image]

Answer (score 16):

Puzzle 4:

> D. Rotate bottom right about its centre by 90degrees, rotate top left. Except for the first row is in the wrong order. Otherwise F could be the right answer. But middle row to bottom row is switch top right, so definitely D.

Puzzle 10:

> C. By rows, vertical lines become inward semi-circles, which become outward semi-circles; by columns, the horizontal lines are transformed.

Answer (score 8):

Puzzle 4

> **D**: Each picture is made of 4 diagonal lines arranged as 2×2. On the first transformation, one of them gets flipped. On the second transformation, the line that's to the opposite corner of the line that was flipped first gets flipped.

Puzzle 10

> **C**: The first transformation is the image "squeezed" by a specific pattern (two circles from the left and right), and the second transformation is the image "expanded" by the same pattern.

Comment: This explanation for 4 is correct!

Answer (score 4):

Puzzle 4

> The answer is D. **Explanation**: 
>  Only red and green lines are toggling in the each row. Transformation always starting from the line pointing to the right. Position (top or bottom) doesn't matter. So, the line inclined to the right rotates to the left in the first step. It's causing both lines always inclined to the left in the middle column. In the next step the second line (opposite diagonally), rotates to the right. Thus, in the end of each row, red and green lines flip vice versa, comparing to the starting position - the right becomes pointing to the left and the left becomes pointing to the right.
>  
>  [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 3):

Puzzle 4

> D - One segment is rotated each time from the first column in a row to the second. From the second to the third column, the segment directly opposite the previously rotated segment is then rotated to reflect the initial segment.

Puzzle 10:

> I think it is A. My reasoning behind this is that they are doing a series of inversions to get the next figure (row and columnwise). So by applying the same inversions to row 2 column 3 and row 3 column 2, we get the circle.

Answer (score 1):

Puzzle 4:

> number of left-top to right-down lines
> [image]

Comment: `A` would also fit in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Puzzle 4. The answer is H.
Notice that 1,3 is the same as 1,1 except rotated 180°. Also 2,1 (the two right arrows), is the same as 2,3 (the two up arrows) except that it is rotated 90°. 2,2 also has it's partner at 3,1. So, all pairs are the same except that they may be rotated a multiple of 90°. So, what about the X at 3,2? It is it's own pair. What about the three lines at 1,2? There is no pair.
So the answer must be H.